# about a property of group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G, G'$ are two groups, and $f$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$.
is the following inclusion  satisfied?
$f^{-1}(x).f^{-1}(y)\subset f^{-1}(x.y)$
for all $x,y \in G'$
and why? thanks.

Comment: This is all about unraveling definitions. If something is in $f^{-1}(x)$, say $a$, what does that mean? What is a homomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $a\in f^{-1} (x)$ and $b\in f^{-1}(y) $ we have $f (ab)=f (a)f (b)=xy $ and so $ab\in f^{-1}(xy) $.

Comment: Ok. And what does it lead if $f^{-1}(xy)$ is empty?

Comment: This argument shows that if $f^{-1}(x) $ and $f^{-1}(y) $ aren't both empty then  $f^{-1}(xy) $ is also not

Comment: Actually I have $f^{-1}(xy)$ is empty, can I conclude that one of $f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(y)$ is empty ?

Comment: Yes! It is equivalent to what I did.